# Error installing nokogiri when updating rails in new installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, installation, nokogiri

I am totally new to Rails and a cautious user of the command line. I want to install the latest version of Rails on Mac OS 10.8. I am following the instructions at http://installrails.com/. I started by running RailsInstaller-1.0.4-osx-10.7.app, which successfully installed Rails 3.2.12.

```
$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.12
$ gem -v
1.8.25
$ gem update --system
...
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.4.6
```

I then continued with the update steps.

I have successfully run [these commands](http://installrails.com/steps/update_ruby),

```
$ sudo rvm get stable
$ rvm install 2.0.0 \
      --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr \
      --verify-downloads 1
...
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.26.11 (latest...)
$ /bin/bash --login
$ rvm use --default 2.0.0
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [x86_64-darwin12.6.0]
```

But then, when I type...

```
$ rails --version
```

I am told...

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system.
```

... although earlier, the same command told me that Rails 3.2.12 was installed. I am guessing that Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 3.2.12 are not compatible. So [I continue](http://installrails.com/steps/update_rails).

Now, when I run the command...

```
$ sudo gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

... I get this error:

```
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/install.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

When I look at the contents of the install.log, I see this:

```
make  install-recursive
Making install in include
Making install in libxml
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ../.././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2/libxml'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 SAX.h entities.h encoding.h parser.h parserInternals.h xmlerror.h HTMLparser.h HTMLtree.h debugXML.h tree.h list.h hash.h xpath.h xpathInternals.h xpointer.h xinclude.h xmlIO.h xmlmemory.h nanohttp.h nanoftp.h uri.h valid.h xlink.h xmlversion.h DOCBparser.h catalog.h threads.h globals.h c14n.h xmlautomata.h xmlregexp.h xmlmodule.h xmlschemas.h schemasInternals.h xmlschemastypes.h xmlstring.h xmlunicode.h xmlreader.h relaxng.h dict.h '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2/libxml'
install: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2/libxml/SAX.h: Permission denied
make[4]: *** [install-xmlincHEADERS] Error 71
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Following tips in other answers to similar questions, I have run:

- `$ gem update --system`
- `brew update`
- `gem install nokogiri`

What else can I try?

Comment: `sudo rvm get stable`? No. Never. Ever. Using `sudo` escalates your permissions to root, which causes any changes to occur outside your RVM sandbox and into the system supplied Ruby. That's not what you want. Instead, you need to simply use `rvm get stable`. If you followed instructions that installed RVM outside your home directory (not in ~/.rvm) then use remove RVM and reinstall using a normal single-user installation following the directions at [RVM's install page](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). Always follow the directions at RVMs site, not at other sites, as the authors know best.

Comment: Run `rvm info` and paste the output into your question, formatting it for readability.

Comment: Ruby is well beyond 2.0.0 now so you might want to consider using a more recent version also.